# facebook and twitter connectivity with sencha touch 2 native app android

Tags: facebook, extjs, twitter, cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I am creating a native app for android using sencha touch 2.2.1

I want to integrate the feature of social media sharing (Facebook and Twitter).

The idea is ,there will be list of images and few buttons under each image. When the user clicks on the share button, Facebook and Twitter icons will popup and if user click on facebook, than that particular image will get posted on users wall(if he/she is already logged in, otherwise will open facebook login window). Same will happen for Twitter.

I am able to implement this thing with sencha webapp. Becuase on the webapp, facebook is getting its fallback url and it posted the image successfully. But when I created an apk of my application then the sharing code is not working.

It is showing error - "URL not allowed.......". I think it is an issue of fallback url. 
I used facebook sdk also but it did not work for me. I also tried with combination of sencha Touch and Phonegap but still the same error as mentioned above.

Please share if anybody implemented similar to this type of project.

Comment: heyy did u checked https://github.com/SenchaArchitect/JogWithFriends/tree/master/JogWithFriends. It is an app that connects FB with Sencha

Comment: I checked it but JofWithFriends is a web app and I am looking solution for a native app.

Comment: I am looking solution for a native app?? You are not using sencha then??

Comment: If you are looking forsencha buil then go through http://www.sencha.com/blog/announcing-sencha-touch-2-3-html5-for-ios7-touch-grid-cordova-support-more/ and http://www.sencha.com/blog/a-sencha-touch-mvc-application-with-phonegap/. it might help you.